# understanding derivation of golden ration convergence for the secant method

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods

I have just worked through the error analysis of the secant method to find:
\begin{equation}
e_{n+1} \approx \dfrac{f''(r)}{2f'(r)}e_ne_{n-1}
\end{equation}

Where $e_n = |x_n - r|$ $r$ is a zero of $f$ and $x_n$ is our sequence. I am having difficulty understanding what my book is saying. It says:

we postulate the following asymptotic relationship ($x_n\sim y_n$ means $\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{x_n}{y_n}=1$):
\begin{align}
|e_{n+1}| &\sim A|e_n|^\alpha \\
\implies |e_n| \sim A|e_{n-1}|^\alpha &\land |e_{n-1}| \sim(A^{-1}|e_n|)^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}
\end{align}

From the first equation we can substitute the asymptotic values of $|e_{n+1}|$ and $|e_{n-1}|$. We get:
\begin{align}
A|e_n|^\alpha \sim& |C||e_n|A^{\frac{-1}{\alpha}}|e_n|^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}\\
A^{1+\frac{1}{\alpha}}|C|^{-1} \sim& |e_n|^{1-\alpha +\frac{1}{\alpha}}
\end{align}

Now here is the part that I do not understand. The book says:

"Since the left side of this relation is a nonzero constant while $e_n\to 0$, we conclude that $1-\alpha+\frac{1}{\alpha}=0$"

Why do they conclude $1-\alpha+\frac{1}{\alpha} = 0$? This would give us $0^0=1$. Is this the only choice we have to make the right-hand-side of the equation nonzero?

Comment: Yes, if $1 - \alpha + \frac{1}{\alpha} < 0$, the right hand side would tend to $\infty$, and if $1 - \alpha + \frac{1}{\alpha} > 0$, it would tend to $0$. So $0$ is the only option.

Comment: I think I get it. You want to think of the right hand side $|e_n|$ as a very tiny number, not literally as $0$.

Comment: Well, you might perchance occasionally have $e_n = 0$, then the asymptotic equalities won't make sense anymore. But in general, you will never hit the exact zero, so $\lvert e_n\rvert > 0$ always. But $e_n \to 0$.